# In k8s, failed to access service via Nginx

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I would like to access backend service via Nginx as reversed proxy, tls is enabled. However, it complained `502 Bad Gateway` error. There should be something wrong in the config, but I cannot tell, please help if there is any suggestion:

nginx.conf:

```
server {
    # listen             8080;
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name loki-gateway.logging.svc.cluster.local;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/tls.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/tls.key;

    location = / {
        return 200 'OK';
        auth_basic off;
    }

    location = /memberlist {
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass       https://loki-write.logging.svc.cluster.local:3100$request_uri;
    }
```

}

nginx svc:

```
loki-gateway                ClusterIP   10.96.126.183   <none>        80/TCP,8443/TCP
```

nginx pod:

```
loki-gateway-84ccff7fd7-nt49p   1/1     Running   0          16m   172.16.135.144
```

No matter from where I curl either the gateway service or pod, the response is the same, except curl the "/".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 502 Bad Gateway error in Nginx can be caused by various factors, including connectivity issues, server overload, DNS problems, firewall restrictions, and misconfigurations.

In your case, the buffer configuration is lacking on your nginx which can lead to potential "upstream sent too big header" error.

You might want to try adding this buffer config to the Nginx server block:

```
server {
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
    proxy_buffers 4 512k;
    proxy_buffer_size 256k;
    # rest of the nginx config
}
```

This can help mitigate the "upstream sent too big header" error and resolve the 502 Bad Gateway issue.

If this doesn't resolve your 502 Bad Gateway, try to examine nginx error logs `/var/log/nginx/error.log` and look for specific error messages and warnings.

Comment: Thanks and I finally found the issue is owning to the cert configuration, but really appreciate for your comment, I will take it as the one.